# Inserting text into the text field is not happening in IE 11

Tags: ruby, internet-explorer, selenium, internet-explorer-11, watir

I am trying to input text into the text box in 'www.google.com' and though it says the text field is present it doesn't input the data into the text field. The same works fine in FF 46.0 and chrome.

Below is my code

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'watir'

browser = Watir::Browser.new(:ie)
browser.goto('www.google.com')

browser.wait_until(60) {
    browser.div(:id, 'sb_ifc0').present?
}
if browser.div(:id, 'sb_ifc0').present?
    p 'search bar'
end

if browser.input(:class, 'gsfi').present?
    p 'input present'
    browser.text_field(:class, 'gsfi').set('watir')
    p browser.text_field(:class, 'gsfi').value        
    browser.send_keys :enter
end
```

Output for ie browser is as below

```
"search bar"
"input present"
""
```

Also please note, i am running the selenium hub and node in the background. There is no issue when the hub and node is running in the foreground

I am using the below setup selenium standalone server 2.53.1, watir gem version 5.0.0, selenium-webdriver gem version 2.53.1, IE version 11, IEDriverServer_Win32_2.53.1.

Answer (score 0):

On `http://www.google.com` the input box was `<input name="q" ... >` and has no `class`, so watir was unable to find it.

Change your `text_field` lookup to use `name` instead:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'watir'

browser = Watir::Browser.new 
browser.goto('www.google.com')

browser.text_field(:name => 'q').set('watir')
browser.button(:type => 'submit').click

p browser.url
```

I also had to change the `send_keys :enter` section because this didn't work for me and I couldn't find a workaround using the enter button.